# Connect to SQL Server Management Studio Express FAIL

Tags: sql-server

I have Visual Studio 2010 Pro on a 32 bit Windows 7 machine.
Am trying to work through a DB tutorial requiring Micorosoft SQL Server Management Studio Express so 
I Installed SQL Server 2005 Express (the 32 bit flavor)

However I can't even connect to the server

For server names I've tried OSR2-PC as indicated by my command line windows >hostname response

I then tried .\sqlexpress per various blog recommendations (see pic)

I get an error popup that says:

*"Additional information:
-> This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 servers "*

Would greatly appreciate help.

Comment: Did you install SQL Management Studio by itself or the database engine as well?  It sounds like your versions don't match up.

Comment: I don't think you installed what you think you installed. What does Management Studio say in Help|About? What version is listed in SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Services > the instance you're trying to connect to, right-click, Properties, Advanced, File Version?

Answer (score 0):

Check the SQL services that are running by executing services.msc.  Installed SQL Server instances will be shown along with the instance name.  Sometimes the instance name is not the same as the hostname.

Comment: It's very rare, actually, that a named instance name is the same as the hostname.